# Azure SQL Server - New field caused error and Full Text Index drop on table

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I just tried to add a new field to an **existing** table in Azure SQL Server using the designer GUI view (not pure T-SQL) of SSMS and got the following error:

> 'MyTable (dbo)' table saved successfully
>
> Error creating or modifying full-text index FullText_for_[MyTable].
>
> DBCC command ‘CALLFULLTEXT’ is not supported in this version of SQL Server

When I went back to the table, the field was added but the Full Text Index has disappeared. I have just had to re-create it. To confirm: the table already had a Full Text Index set up on it *before* I added the new field.

Is there anything I did wrong there? Anything I should be wary of? It's a little disconcerting that the table dropped the index.

Incidentally - I have `prevent saving changes that require table re-creation` unticked in `options > designers`. I understand this could give scope for the error I saw. If this was most likely the cause, how can a new field be added to a table seamlessly?

Answer (score 0):

> Incidentally - I have prevent saving changes that require table re-creation unticked in options > designers. I understand this could give scope for the error I saw. If this was most likely the cause, how can a new field be added to a table seamlessly?

According to this [article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/956176/error-message-when-you-try-to-save-a-table-in-sql-server-saving-changes-is-not-permitted), if you set the saving changes that require table re-creation unticked in options in SSMS, if you change the table it will how “Saving changes is not permitted” error.

> Is there anything I did wrong there? Anything I should be wary of? It's a little disconcerting that the table dropped the index.

According to this article:[Current limitations of Full-Text Search capabilities in Azure SQL Database](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/full-text-search-is-now-available-for-preview-in-azure-sql-database/)

```
Note that Azure SQL Database V12 Full-Text Search functionality represents a subset of the Microsoft SQL Server 2014 release
No support for installation or use of third party filters, including Office and .pdf.
Customers cannot manage service settings for fdhost, all configurations are being managed by the service.
Semantic search, thesaurus and search property lists syntax is not yet enabled.
```

So I guess maybe something wrong with your sql query.

I have written a test demo on my computer(The version of the SSMS is 2014) and it works well. Hope it gives you some tips:

```
CREATE TABLE Persons2 (
    PersonID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    LastName varchar(255),
    FirstName varchar(255),
);

CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG Persons2_catalog;  
GO  

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ui_PersonId ON Persons2(PersonID); 

CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON Persons2 
 (    
  LastName  
     Language 1033,  
  FirstName   
     Language 1033       
 )
  KEY INDEX ui_PersonId  
      ON Persons2_catalog;
```

Comment: I've edited my question - this was an alteration to an existing table with an existing Full Text Index on it via SSMS.

Comment: Do you mean you just add a new field to a table(enable full index )?Does you do some other operation?

Comment: I have a table with data in my database. It has Full-Text Index enabled on it already. I add a new field to the existing table. The Full-Text Index is lost and I see the error stated in my original question. The new field is successfully added.

Comment: I suggest you could retry on the error.Since I have written a test demo on my computer.I define a full text for the table, then I add a new field in the table. It works well. I guess this is caused by SSMS run the sql query, it might have tried connecting to the server and it timed out. On the retry it may success and should run without any issues.